# nginx not running, but listening on port 80

Tags: nginx

I am unable to do `service nginx start` due to:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

But if I then do `service nginx status` I get:

```
 * nginx is not running
```

This is with nginx 1.8 on ubuntu 14.04, and using stop does not work (as it doesn't think it is running)

I know I can just kill the process running on that port, but I need a more graceful way to fix the problem.

I have confirmed that it is nginx listening on port 80 using `netstat -tulpn`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9787/nginx.conf
```

When running `sudo /usr/sbin/nginx -s reload`

```
nginx: [error] open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

I am using AWS OpsWorks (Chef) to manage the infrastructure.
To install nginx I am using the https://github.com/miketheman/nginx/tree/2.7.x cookbook, and installing via the repo. Run list = [nginx::repo, nginx::default]

The first time boot works absolutely fine, but a subsequent setup call causes a setup failure.

Results from `ps aux | grep nginx`

```
root      9791  0.0  0.0  31504  2184 ?        Ss   10:12   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
www-data 14571  0.0  0.0  32036  1976 ?        S    10:13   0:00 nginx: worker process                   
www-data 14572  0.0  0.0  32036  2224 ?        S    10:13   0:00 nginx: worker process                   
www-data 14573  0.0  0.0  32036  1976 ?        S    10:13   0:00 nginx: worker process                   
www-data 14574  0.0  0.0  32036  1976 ?        S    10:13   0:00 nginx: worker process                   
www-data 14575  0.0  0.0  32036  1976 ?        S    10:13   0:00 nginx: worker process                   
www-data 14576  0.0  0.0  32036  1976 ?        S    10:13   0:00 nginx: worker process                   
www-data 14577  0.0  0.0  32036  1976 ?        S    10:13   0:00 nginx: worker process                   
www-data 14578  0.0  0.0  32036  1976 ?        S    10:13   0:00 nginx: worker process                   
www-data 14579  0.0  0.0  32036  1976 ?        S    10:13   0:00 nginx: worker process                   
www-data 14580  0.0  0.0  32036  1976 ?        S    10:13   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

If I run `echo '9791' | sudo tee /run/nginx.pid` nginx reports that is now running. Previously the pid file was empty.

So the root problem appears to be that the pid file is getting truncated.

Comment: could you paste the PID into /run/nginx.pid or wherever the service control is looking?

Comment: So what is listening on that port?

Comment: @Tim Just collecting the data.

Comment: @EEAA It is listening on port 80, that's not the problem. The problem is that it does not think it is running, meaning I can not ask it to restart or even stop.

Comment: also have you tried controlling nginx directly? like `/usr/local/sbin/nginx -s reload`

Comment: How sure are you that it is running? What gave you done to verify this? Use other tools to corroborate what the init script is telling you.

Comment: run `netstat -nlp |grep :80` as root to confirm that it's really nginx that is listening on that port.

Comment: There's surely some other process is using port 80. It might be possible that a nginx process could not end cleanly. You need to kill that process & restart it, I think that's the only solution.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I have provided the info on the ports.

Comment: @Tim Added information about the reload.

Comment: If nginx is really the listening process then like my first comment, can you just reinstate the PID file? What do you get with `ps aux | grep nginx` Maybe you have apache running by mistake or maybe nginx has just lost its pid file somehow?

Comment: @Tim provided aux info.

Comment: so it is running. What happens if you `echo 9791 > /run/nginx.pid` and then try the service status again?

Comment: @Tim Updated the question

Comment: Have you recently updated nginx? Maybe just try to test your config ( nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf ) and if it'll be ok - killall nginx and then just start?

Answer (score 0):

Run
`sudo fuser -k 80/tcp`

This kills the nginx worker listening on port 80, allowing you to run nginx.